# Correct way to propagate aloe from leaf

Tags: propagation, aloe

I have seen a lot of videos on how to propagate an aloe with leaf cuttings. They usually let the leaf stand for a few days, then stuck it into wet soil.

It does not work for me - the leaf just starts to rot after a few weeks.

What I tried

- put leaf into soil, with and without rooting hormone
- put leaf into wet clay perlites
- wrap peroxide sterilized leaves into wet kitchen towel and foil

Result was always a rotting leaf. Can this plant propagated by leaf cutting? If yes, then how?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try leaving the leaf somewhere completely dry until it starts to grow roots. For example just put it on a dry piece of paper, on a window sill where gets plenty of light.

Since it is a succulent plant, there is plenty of water stored in the leaf already. It doesn't need any more until it starts to grow. In fact it will start to grow roots as a response to losing its stored water.